# Page counter is always Page 1 of 0 but I have 3 pages

Tags: html, css, pdf, counter

Here's my code:

```
<div id="pageNumber"></div>

    #pageNumber {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        font-size: small;
    }
    
    
    
    
    @media print {  
        @page 
        { 
            counter-increment: page;
            size: auto;
            margin: 25mm 25mm 25mm 25mm;
        } 
        
        #pageNumber::after {
            counter-increment: page;
            content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
        }

    
    }
```

It always returns Page 1 of 0.
I'm trying to make it Page 1 of 3 Page 2 of 3 and so on. What could be wrong?

Comment: This part of print CSS is unfamiliar to me, but you are incrementing `page` twice. `pages` seems not defined anywhere.

Comment: what should be the correct approach?

Comment: Where is the HTML? This has nothing to do with CSS.

Comment: sorry, edited...